# Can I Culture Bomb far away?

Tags: civilization-5

I have my eyes on a luxury resource on neutral territory, very far away from my cities, behind the territories of other civilizations.

But I don't want to settle a city there because of the effects on social policy costs.

My plan is to send over a Great Artist to Culture Bomb the place, a worker to improve the tile, and some security units. I'm willing to take the security risk.

Can the plan work? Can one culture-bomb far from one's territory? Does an improved tile far from my roads and cities make the resource available to me?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, Culture Bombs can only be used on tiles on or adjacent to your territory.

Comment: "Culture Bomb" was an ability of Great Artists before the Gods and Kings and Brave New World expansions. "Construct Citadel" on Great Generals replaces that ability and has the same location restrictions.